# Single Sign On Marketing cloud via Ws02

Tags: marketing-cloud, single-sign-on

We are trying to enable SSO for our Marketing cloud users. We are enabling sso via WS02 and not using Service cloud as the Idp. in MC, We have created the key and enabled SSO for users. Marketing cloud created a SSO Single Sign-On Link which redirects to our WS02 instance.

Is there a way for users to use the same url they logged to MC prior to us enabling sso (via https//:exacttarget.com rather than the sso link created by mc) where the exact target login page display sso login... The same way service cloud can display sso on the salesforce login page? Hope this  making sense?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share steps how you enabled SSO via WS02. You would have required Entity ID and Federation ID. Also, you did it using SAML?

Comment: Hi Krati, we managed to make it work. The only issue we having now is that when we log out of mc, the url redirects to mc error page rather than the mc loginpage or ws02..same settings was applied to the  sandbox prior to implementing live and ut 4edirected to login page not an error page...any idea why this could be?

Comment: Did you configure Single Logout Service Location and Single logout service binding while creating SSO key? It affects where the contact is redirected after logging out from application. See the 7 point (guided configuration) here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_create_a_key.htm&type=5

And if yours was a Paste Metadata, check the Metadata if it contains these attributes.

Comment: Hi KratiYes we have configured Single Logout Service Location and Single logout service binding while creating SSO key, it might be an issue from Ws02 side...

Comment: By adding SLO in IDP, the logout redirection worked.

Comment: Awesome! Congrats on successfully enabling SSO for your account. Share best practices that came while enabling SSO if any. :) @Vavan